# Vue I want an image to follow the mouse

Tags: vuejs2

I am having trouble with a Vue component https://jsfiddle.net/shawnswebsites/fep1p02c/20/.  I have a div in the component and when the user's mouse enters the div I want an image to be shown and I want the image to follow the mouse.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   showImage: false,
    page: {
     left : 0,
      top: 0
      },
     },
     methods: {
            onMouseMove(e) {
                console.log('page x: ' + this.page.left);
                this.page.left = e.pageX;
                this.page.top = e.pageY;
            }
     }
  })
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 40px;
}

.image {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container"           
  @mouseenter="showImage = true"
             @mousemove.self="onMouseMove($event)"
             @mouseleave="showImage = false">
    
  </div>
  <img v-show="showImage" class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" :style="{ left: page.left + 'px', top: page.top + 'px' }">
</div>
```

I use a @mouseenter to show the image and @mouseleave to hide the image.  However, @mouseleave is still being called as I scroll over the div, which is causing the image to blink on and off.  Can any help?

Comment: Try placing the img tag inside the div and set pointer-events: none; on the image

Answer (score 0):

As said [Oxcarga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888056/oxcarga) in the comment below you need to add `pointer-events: none;` to your image style:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow:hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```